# rstudio chunks not appearing after chunk that chunk that created them

Tags: rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, chunks

I don't quite understand placement of chunks in an Rstudio notebook.  I need to know how to make the chunks and results in the markdown appear in the same order as the original document and be able to control which are included using the `include=` chunk option.

````
  ---
title: "Test markdown"
output:
  html_notebook: default
---

```{r, setup, include=FALSE}
# set default chunk options:w

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, include = FALSE, fig.width = 8, collapse = TRUE, warning = FALSE)

```

Note 0

```{r}
# Comment
c <- 92461110
m <- 7056556
```

```{r, include=TRUE}
c
```
Note 1
```{r}
paste("Nothing")
```

Note 2

```{r,include=TRUE}
paste("Something")
```

```{r, include=TRUE}
paste("something else")
```
````

I should get

```
Test Markdown

Note 0

92461110

Note 1

Note 2

[1] "Something"

[1] "Something else"
```

Instead I get

```
Test markdown

Note 0

Note 1

Note 2

[1] "Nothing"

[1] "Something"
```

Comment: Copypasting your example in a notebook, I actually get exactly what you should get.

Comment: So much for a reproducible example.